# Javascript - I have to use sleep function for run my function

Tags: javascript, youtube-javascript-api

I use youtube data api. I run my code, in that.

```
keyWordsearch()
```

It's not working. Chrome console say "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setApiKey' of undefined"

But it is working strangely

```
setTimeout(keyWordsearch, 1000);
```

My all code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo SITE_PUBLIC; ?>/bootstrap-3.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {   

            var domain = '<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>';

                    function makeRequest(q, resultsIndex) {
                        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                                q: q,
                                part: 'snippet',
                                type: 'video', 
                                maxResults: 1,
                                videoCategoryId:10
                        });
                        request.execute(function(response)  {                                                                                    
                                $('#results').empty()
                                var srchItems = response.result.items;                      
                                $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
                                vidTitle = item.snippet.title;  
                                vidThumburl =  item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;                 
                                vidThumbimg = '';

                                    html = '<div  class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> \
                                         <iframe height="315" \
                                        src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+ item.id.videoId +'" \
                                        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> \
                                        </div><br>'

                                $('.musics-results:eq('+resultsIndex+')').append(html);                         

                        })  
                    })  
                }   
                    function keyWordsearch(){
                        gapi.client.setApiKey('blabla');
                        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {

                                $('.musics-results').each(function( index, value){
                                    data = jQuery.parseJSON( $(this).attr('value') );
                                    $.each(data['names'], function( index2, value2 ) {
                                        makeRequest(value2, index);
                                    });

                                });


                        });
                        }

                    //setTimeout(keyWordsearch, 1000);
                    keyWordsearch();
    })
    </script>
```

What should i do? Thanks  in advance

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You need to wait for the `googleApiClientReady`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

You are just loading the API client wrapper script; it may do background loading of additional scripts and will call the function you provided, `googleApiClientReady`, when it's done loading.

Without `setTimeout`, your `keywordSearch` function runs too soon, before the API client has actually been loaded. With `setTimeout`, you just got lucky that the client got loaded within those 1000 milliseconds, but this won't be the case on a slow connection.

So you should put your startup code into a function named `googleApiClientReady` (or change that name). See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples for working examples.

Comment: `What should i do?` This.

Comment: keywordSearch function did not work too soon. I not understand your sentence "So you should put your startup code into a function named googleApiClientReady (or change that name)"